# Jumping to-and fro between Kernel and user code in Linux

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, mmu

I am doing some kernel hacking on Linux running x86-64 for a research project. From a kernel routine I need to jump to a user mode code page and immediately return back to kernel code. In other words, I need to do a trampoline on user code while executing in the kernel.

I am wondering whether this can be at all possible or not. If possible, can somebody give some idea how this can be achieved?

Comment: I edited your question to remove your signature line, which is [discouraged](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#signatures) at Stack Exchange. I'm surprised nobody corrected you before, so I edited a few of your other questions as well. If you look around on this site, you'll notice that no one else uses a signature.

Comment: rolled back to the original to correct title error introduced by editor

Answer (score 3):

It is unlikely to be possible "easily".

Without knowing your application, and without suggesting that you rethink your kernel<->app interface, a possible hack for you could work like this: have the application register a piece of trampoline code with your kernel component by just passing the address of that code. The trampoline code would execute your "real" user mode function, then issue another syscall or exception to return to the kernel.

While this is not exactly a user-mode subroutine, it gets reasonably close: when your application calls whatever kernel function needs to do the callback, the kernel function can just save the real return address, change it to the registered trampoline address and return to user mode. The trampoline will call the function, the syscall/exception following it will kick you back into the kernel and you can continue whatever you were doing there.

You probably don't need to worry about security anyway, but if you do you'd probably have to make sure the "return from trampoline" syscall is only accepted from processes where you still have an open trampoline hack going on.

You can also take a look at how signals work; they are about having the kernel interrupt an application and having the application invoke a signal handler; a signal-like implementation would even work without your application having an active syscall going on (but it will also have all the limitations of a signal handler).

In fact, maybe you can just use a signal? Again, take a look at how signals work in the kernel, and just signal your user-code. Install the appropiate signal handler in your application, and have the signal handler invoke the "return from userspace trampoline" syscall.

Either way, it sounds a bit... hackish. Without ever having done any kernel stuff, I would assume that interfacing with your application through a device node, socket or similar mechanism would probably be a much better way... or just have your syscalls return a "to do" result item to the application telling it to invoke siome user space code and report back with another syscall.